# New comment system on Pages shows in the wierd order?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Is there any chance to get some "settings" for the comments order on Facebook page? We activated the new "answer mode" or something like that, so people has the ability to reply to anyone comment.

But, what's wierd, when somebody new add the comment it order to somewhere between the discussion. Where is settings - when we can sort the parent comments by date?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that Facebook sorts these comments by relevance for the current user, based on relations with poster, previous likes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no setting for the ordering of comments. They are all based on an interactivity score. So the higher the interactivity is, the sooner it is ordered whithin the comments.

you can find more info about this here: http://allfacebook.com/replies-ranked-comments_b113737